Align images centrally in their cell (for all the worksheets)
I have the code that loops through all my worksheets and resizes all the images but is there anyway to make it so that the images also align center within their cells?
Sub ChangeAllPics()
Dim s As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each s In ws.Shapes
        s.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        s.Width = 62
        s.Height = 63
    Next s
Next ws
End Sub


Try using Shape.TopLeftCell property. You can set a range variable on it and use it to place your image accordingly.

Something like s.Left = s.TopLeftCell.Left + (s.TopLeftCell.Width / 2) - (s.Width / 2).  If, on the other hand, you're placing your images within the cell you can just use cell.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter (365 now has the option to place within cells or over cells).

Each Shape will have a Shape.TopLeftCell property, which contains the cell that its top-left corner overlaps with.
This cell will then have the Range.Top, Range.Left, Range.Width, and Range.height properties.
(It will also have the Range.MergeArea property, in case a shape sits in a Merged Area instead of a single cell).
Now, to centre a shape in the cell, you want to set the Left of the Shape to the Left of the Cell, plus half the Width of the Cell, minus half the Width of the Shape.
'Cell:                   |            [-------------]
'Shape:                  |{=======}
'
'Cell Left:              |→→→→→→→→→→→→[-------------]
'                        |            {=======}
'
'Plus half Cell Width:   |            [→→→→→→|------]
'                        |                   {=======}
'
'Minus half Shape Width: |            [--¦←←←|------]
'                        |               {===¦===}     

Then you do the same thing for the Top and Height of the Shape and Cell.
(You are forcing the size of the Shapes to be 62*63, so we could use 31 and 31.5 as our values there — however, for versatility, I am going to avoid that)
Sub ChangeAllPics()
    Dim s As Shape, c AS Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each s In ws.Shapes
            s.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            s.Width = 62
            s.Height = 63
            
            Set c = s.TopLeftCell.MergeArea
            s.Top = c.Top+(c.Height-s.Height)/2
            s.Left = c.Left+(c.Width-s.Width)/2
            Set c = Nothing
    Next s, ws
End Sub

